# how to refresh page when routing url changes in angular

Tags: angular

I have a sidebar where list of items are fetched from api and are displayed.  When one of the item is selected from the side bar it goes to a page where another drop down is there and data of selected item is displayed on that drop down. But when i change the item from side bar, the page where data of selected item should come, does not refreshed.

*my side bar component.html*

```
<li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let data of getItemList">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
     class="nav-link text-white p-3 sidebar-link" 
     (click)="list(data.Id)">
       <i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i>{{data.ItemName}}</a>
</li>
```

*my sidebar.component.ts*

```
   list(id) {
    this.router.navigate(["/dashboard/item/item-home/" + id]);
   }
```

*my item-home.component.html*

```
          <select
                type="number"
                class="form-control"
                (change)="onChangeItemData$event.target.value)"
                formControlName="GroupId"
              >
                <option hidden value="" disabled="true"
                  >Please select Item data
                </option>
                <option
                  *ngFor="let group of itemInfo"
                  type="number"
                  [ngValue]="group.Id"
                >
                  {{ group.Name }}
                </option>
          </select>
```

*my item-home.component.ts*

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(
    (routeParam) => {
      const id = parseInt(routeParam.get("id"));
      this.itemId = id;
    },
    (err) => { }
  );
  this.fetchGroupInfoByUseCases(this.itemId)
}

fetchGroupInfoByUseCases(Id) {
  this.usecaseServ
    .getGroupInfoByUseCase(Id)
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.groupInfo = res;
    });
}
```

Comment: you should be calling `this.fetchGroupInfoByUseCases(this.itemId)` in route param subscription block

Comment: @NileshPatel plz add an answer so that i can upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any async task(promise or subscription) needs to be resolved before you can do any further task. so, `fetchGroupInfoByUseCases` should be get called when route params gets resolved.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(
    (routeParam) => {
      const id = parseInt(routeParam.get("id"));
      this.itemId = id;
      this.fetchGroupInfoByUseCases(this.itemId)
    },
    (err) => { }
  );
}

fetchGroupInfoByUseCases(Id) {
  this.usecaseServ
    .getGroupInfoByUseCase(Id)
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.groupInfo = res;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an event listener on the `Angular Router.url`.
Sample code:

1. Initialise the Angular Router

```
public route: any = '';

constructor( private _router: Router ) {
    this.route = this._router.url;
  }
```

2. Add the event listener to ngOnInit

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    )
      .subscribe(event => {
        this.route = event['url'];
        console.log(this.route)
        // do something here when route changes
      });
  }
```